# What is the difference between jquery-ui and jquery-ui-min?

Tags: jquery

What is the difference between:

jquery-ui.min.js

and

jquery-ui.js

The datapicker widget seems to work with jquery-ui but not with the jquery-ui.min.js

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: As with virtually all Javascript libraries, the `.min` version is the *minified* version. It's exactly the same, but the file is smaller because the code is compressed/minified.

Comment: Nothing, just [minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) process.

Comment: If you have problems getting the datepicker working, ask about *that* and not about something you think might be the problem. You'll solve the issue much faster that way.

Comment: i think in `juery-ui-min.js` you need to add `jquery-datepicker*.js` file seperatly  as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no difference.

in jquery-ui.js the code is indented making it readable in developement environment, while the min file the code is minified by removing comments and spaces thus reducing the file ready for production deployment. The minified file is used for production because of less file size